# How to prevent ASP.NET web site initialization error if to abort request early?

Tags: asp.net, ihttpmodule

I tried to [URLRewrite](http://www.iis.net/urlrewrite) module to redirect, rewrite and abort requests to site.
But site shown error.

I wrote down `IHttpModule` which does similar, and calls `HttpApplication.Context.Response.End();` in 'HttpApplication.BeginRequest'.
This leads to direct jump into `EndRequest` event. Site does not expect this and throws InvalidOperationException in its `EndRequest` indicating that trying to clean some database code even without initialization. The same with `URLRewrite`.

I think this is because `End()` call skips initialization.

How to prevent this error to be shown to user? Kind of swallow it without ability to modify 3rd party site.

I experimenting with other `HttpApplication` events and do not want request to be handled, i.e. nothing written down to database as part of request. Not results here yet, what other options?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET and IIS are you dealing with? If you are attempting to create pretty URLs, such as those in ASP.NET MVC, you can take a look at the Routing mechanism available out of the box in ASP.NET. [See this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing), assuming you're on a WebForms project.

Comment: I use ASP.NET Web Forms in IIS 7.5 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Awesome. Assuming that the URL Rewrite you talked about is for simply doing pretty URLs, such as `~/Directory/Action/SomeValue` which you expect it to be `~/Directory/Page.aspx?action=SomeValue`, I highly encourage you to use Routes. See the link I posted above. Routes are native to ASP.NET, so they're technically not a URL rewriter.